# Spark : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ljava/util/Iterator;I)Ljava/util/List

Tags: java, maven, hbase, apache-spark

I use spark 1.0.0. I execute this code and then get the following exception. I have figured out the exception is caused by takeOrdered(int num, Comparator) method of JavaPairRDD. How can i solve this problem ?

Maven dependency of Spark :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my code.

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(
            master);
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName);
    try {
        HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);

        if (!admin.isTableAvailable(tableName)) {
            HTableDescriptor tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(
                    TableName.valueOf(tableName));
            admin.createTable(tableDesc);
        }

        JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> hBaseRDD = sc
                .newAPIHadoopRDD(
                        conf,
                        TableInputFormat.class,
                        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
                        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result.class);

        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = hBaseRDD
                .mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>, String, Integer>() {

                    /**
                     * 
                     */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = -77767105936599216L;

                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(
                            Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> tuple)
                            throws Exception {
                        Result r = tuple._2;
                        String userId = new String(r.getRow());

                        int i = 0;

                        for (Cell c : r.rawCells())
                            if (compareDatesInMilis(now, c.getTimestamp()) <= numberOfDay)
                                i++;

                        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(userId, i);
                    }
                });

        List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> l = pairs.takeOrdered(10,
                new TupleComparator());
        admin.close();
        sc.stop();

    } catch (MasterNotRunningException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ZooKeeperConnectionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get this exception.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ljava/util/Iterator;I)Ljava/util/List;
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1.apply(RDD.scala:1043)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1.apply(RDD.scala:1040)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:559)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:559)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-06-25 16:48:49,544 ERROR [Executor task launch worker-1] executor.ExecutorUncaughtExceptionHandler (Logging.scala:logError(95)) - Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-1,5,main]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ljava/util/Iterator;I)Ljava/util/List;
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1.apply(RDD.scala:1043)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1.apply(RDD.scala:1040)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:559)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:559)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Have you added the googly collection dependency cause it doesn't look like?

Comment: Yes, i have already added it.

Comment: It's probably a matter of versions. Try to update the library to the latest version

Comment: It's already the latest version. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my spark maven dependency version and the problem is solved. Here is my new spark version :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.